# Linking MSSQL server to MySQL server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

I'm in a difficult situation where I need to work with an outdated server. I believe that its MSSQL 2000 if not 2002, whatever the case it NEEDS to be updated but IT refuses out of fear of some legacy things breaking.

I need information from that database in an app that I'm building that is going to be on a different server (that is MySQL based) but this data is dynamic and is still being updated so I can't just copy the table. It would need to be linked with the old server. Is there a way or a set up guide I can look over that connects a MSSQL server to a MySQL server? Is the connection two way or one way?

I've read about connecting a MySQL server to a MSSQL server but I need the opposite if its not two way since the MSSQL isn't the main one I'm working on.

Comment: You scenario is not very clear, but, MSSQL can export as SQL file or CSv, and MySQL can Import SQLFile or CSV file, so you can setup a hourly schedule or something that update 2 database... Or can write script that can connect to both MySQL and MSSQL. Please explain scenarios of your application I can guide you.

Comment: Connect both databases directly from the application.

Comment: I honestly didn't know the option to connect via the app was possible. This would be a lot easier for me. Thanks for this information Fanda. I'm using the newwest version of PHP however, would it be able to connect to a MSSQL 2000?